# Open multiple files at once not after one another with Automator

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, automation, finder, automator

I am trying to create an automator script to export selected Fotos and open them with Outlook to send via email. Outlook does not support the share sheet and that's why we have to take this detour.
My problem is that if I try to open multiple photos at once with automator a new mail is created for every photo that is in the input. If I selected multiple photos in the finder and open them with outlook then they are all put in to a single mail.
Do you know another action that opens them in the correct way like the finder does?

[image: this is the action that does not do it in the correct way.]

Comment: I'm afraid that you need the help of script.